Calculating permutations of unique strings from combinations of letters and numbers
My problem is as follows: how many ways are there to create unique strings by choosing six letters from the alphabet (duplicates allowed) and two numeric digits (duplicates allowed)? E.g. ABCDEF12 or AABBCC99
My knowledge of combinatorics is very rusty unfortunately. I thought I could break the problem down like so:
Choosing six unordered letters with repetition allowed:
$$
\binom{n + r - 1}{r} = \binom{26 + 6 - 1}{6} = 736,281
$$
Choosing two unordered numbers with repetition allowed:
$$
\binom{n + r - 1}{r} = \binom{10 + 2 - 1}{2} = 55
$$
Number of ways to permute 8 characters (six letters and two numbers) without repetition:
$$
\binom{8}{8} = 8! = 40,320
$$
Number of permutations of strings with six letters and two numbers:
$$
736,281 \times 55 \times 40,320 = 1.6327767e^{12}
$$
Of course, I'm not sure how to account for repetitions. One problem (at least!) with my approach is that the string $A_1A_2BCDE12$ is treated as being different to $A_2A_1BCDE12$ when they should only be counted once as they are not considered unique.

Explicitly:
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{8}{2}~$ choices, for which positions will be numbers rather than letters.  Once this is determined, since the sampling is done with replacement, there are $~26~$ choices for each of the $~6~$ letter positions, and $~10~$ choices for each of the $~2~$ number positions.
Therefore, the computation is
$$\binom{8}{2} \times 26^6 \times 10^2.$$

Yes, as you observe, your approach over-counts. Correcting your computation is hard, since different sets of characters have different multiplicities of each character, you would need a complicated sum to eliminate the repeated strings.
I propose the following instead:

Choose ordered lists of letter and numbers.
Count the number of ways to interleave the two lists while preserving the order of the sub-lists.

Both parts are pretty simple.
Choosing ordered lists
There are $n^k$ choices of length-$k$ ordered lists of $n$ objects with repetition allowed.
Use this formula to determine the number of lists of 6 letters and the number of lists of 2 numerals.
Chose an interleaving pattern
This is sometimes referred to as a "stars and bars" problem for the sake of a visual representation. Given $a$ "stars" and $b$ "bars", all indistinguishable, how many different ways can we order them? The answer is equivalent to choosing an unordered set of $a$ positions for the stars from the $a+b$ total positions: ${a +b \choose a}$.
Use this formula to determine, given a fixed ordered list of 6 numbers and 2 numerals, the number of ways to interleave the two.
Conclude
Multiple the number of lists of letters, the number of lists of numerals, and number of interleaving patterns. As a sanity check, the result will be smaller than the number you computed.
